# Swift Xcode 6 gives SIGABRT when Testing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, xctest

I recently updated to the most recent version of Xcode (6.3) and are now unable to run our tests, which were previously functional.

It throws a SIGABRT with the following information:

> Could not cast value of type 'MyApplication.MyPSClass' (0x109d7f410) to 'MyApplicationTests.MyPSClass' (0x1197ddec0).

MyApplicationTests is the Test Target and MyApplication is the normal application target.

MyApplication uses Parse as our back-end. Is it possible that this error is a result of the Subclassing functionality?

MyClass subclasses PFObject and PFSubclassing as is specified in the Parse's subclassing documentation:

```
class MyPSClass : PFObject, PFSubclassing { ... }
```

The line which shows the "Thread 1: SIGABRT" is:

```
let myPSInstance = MyPSClass.query().getObjectWithId("ParseObjectIDString") as! MyPSClass
```

The Test Class file, which contains this line, looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import XCTest

class MyClassTests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        //...
    }

    func testInit() {
        let myPSInstance = MyPSClass.query().getObjectWithId("ParseObjectIDString") as! MyPSClass
        //...    
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

}
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that in this line:

`let myPSInstance = MyPSClass.query().getObjectWithId("ParseObjectIDString") as! MyPSClass`

You're casting MyPSClass to MyApplicationTests.MyPSClass. You can't tell, because swift uses implicit namespaces (which hides the MyApplicationTests namespace). You can to use:

`let myPSInstance = MyPSClass.query().getObjectWithId("ParseObjectIDString") as! MyApplication.MyPSClass`

Comment: I have tried that, however, I get an error that says "Use of undeclared type 'MyApplication'". Is MyApplication not the correct namespace, or maybe somehow unaccessible? 
I have also tried adding 'import MyApplication', but to no avail. That gives the error "No type names 'MyPSClass' in module 'MyApplication'".

Comment: It was not, but changing it to `public class MyPSClass : PFObject, PFSubclassing { ... }` did not help. It still tries to cast it to MyApplicationTests.MyPSClass.

Comment: You still need to use MyApplication.MyPSClass when calling, and since its now public, it should work.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I had to add `import MyApplication` at the top as well as go through and make all of the methods and variables that I wanted access to public, which seemed excessive.  Does that mean that the class and methods were considered public within its respective target, but were considered private from my test target?

Comment: Yes, private methods are accessible from within the class itself. You had to make things public so your test target can access them. Hooray, have fun with your app!

Comment: So, would there be a better way to be able to test my code than making all these classes and methods public? It seems like bad practice to make everything public only so I can test it. Is there a way to rather include my tests in the namespace?

Comment: So far I haven't figured out how to do something like `using namespace std;` in c++, nor have I figured out how to disable it. Namespaces are implicit and defined as per target basis, so the best/only way is to make everything public.